# Need Help on Page Object Model Implementation

Tags: protractor, pageobjects

I am in a process of implementing Page object Model, I have one query regarding it, please see below:

I have created page files which is having locators and methods for the page, I have spec file in which I am doing the assertions by calling these methods. My question is that for one page I have over 100 test cases, now should I create single assertion file for single tests or should I create 100 assertion file for 100 test.

Please let me know what is the best way to manage it.

Regards,
Manan

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes the most sense to group tests into files by functionality. It's hard to run only some tests from a file, so split out any groups of tests you think you might want to run independently. Are some of them suitable for a quick smoke test suite? Maybe those should be in a separate file.

Comment: I am doing like this by creating separate smoke and functional spec files on basis of windows/features. But sometimes in functional spec there are lot many tests due to which there are over KLOC so in long run it might be difficult to debug/maintain the spec files as spec size will further grow. Your reply assured me that I am moving in right direction, appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to create a new file for neither every assertion nor test case. I am confused by your question because in my understanding, the assertion is part of the test case, and test+assertion are part of the same function (assertion being the end goal of the test).

Regarding the Page Object Model: The important part of the pattern is ensuring the separation of page/DOM detail from test flow (i.e. tests should possess no knowledge of the DOM, but instead rely on page objects to act on actual pages).